# How to extract all elements on specific example with scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to extract all element on [this page](http://gepris.dfg.de/gepris/OCTOPUS?beginOfFunding=&bewilligungsStatus=&context=projekt&continentId=%23&countryKey=%23%23%23&einrichtungsart=-1&fachlicheZuordnung=%23&findButton=historyCall&gefoerdertIn=&hitsPerPage=50&index=0&nurProjekteMitAB=false&oldContinentId=%23&oldCountryId=%23%23%23&oldSubContinentId=%23%23&oldpeo=%23&peo=%23&subContinentId=%23%23&task=doSearchExtended&teilprojekte=true&zk_transferprojekt=false), but it extracts only the first element. How should the xpath expression must be?

```
 def parse(self, response):
    for sel in response.xpath("//*[@id='liste']"):        
        lianjia = lianjiaItem()
        lianjia['name_of_community'] = sel.xpath("div[1]/div[1]/h2/a/text()").extract()
        lianjia['Antragsteller'] = sel.xpath("div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/span[2]/text()").extract()

        yield lianjia
```

Comment: 'Antragsteller' is in this case the 'Sprecher' like 'Dietrich Stoyan' or 'Günter Gauglitz' on this given page. But how must the xpath expression must look. Can you write it

Answer (score 0):

That's because there is only one element with `id` equals 'liste'. You need to iterate through elements that represents individual row of data instead, and extract all the needed information from each row, for example :

```
for sel in response.xpath("//*[@id='liste']/div[contains(@class,'eintrag')]"):        
    lianjia = lianjiaItem()
    lianjia['name_of_community'] = sel.xpath("div[@class='results']/h2/a/text()").extract()
    lianjia['Antragsteller'] = sel.xpath(".//div[span='Sprecher']/span[2]/text()").extract()

    yield lianjia
```

Comment: 'Antragsteller' is in this case the 'Sprecher' like 'Dietrich Stoyan' or 'Günter Gauglitz' on this given page. But how must the xpath expression must look. Can you write it

Comment: Thx. What is the xpath expression for the values of Fachkollegium, DFG-Verfahren, Förderung and the desciption?

Comment: @user3786117 Please take this only as an example. For the long run, I really suggest to learn more about XPath. XPath 1.0 has far fewer keywords compared to most general purpose programming language, so it shouldn't be hard, but will be extremely useful for this kind of task. Thanks

Comment: @user3786117 given the two examples above, you should attempt to figure out the XPath for other elements on your own